# How can i install Python-dev inside a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, porting

I have a docker container `(bash),`i want to install `numpy` inside the container using command `pip intsall numpy` but it gives error  `SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-dev`
And when i try to install python-dev , using command `pip install python-dev` , It gives error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dev (from versions: none)`

Help will be appreciated

Comment: Show us your Dockerfile, or if run in a container the image and all relevant commands!

Comment: FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install firefox && apt-get -y install vim


This is inside my dockerfile

Comment: Add all information to the question by editing it!

Comment: It’s called `python3-dev`.

Comment: still same error @wkl

Comment: It works on my Ubuntu test image using `ubuntu:latest`, and that's [the package name](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/python3-dev).

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried checking your current version of the pre-existing `python-dev` package? You can use `python dev -v` for this.

Then you can try installing/updating `python-dev` to the latest version

```
apt-get install -f python3.10 -dev
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It gives error that   python-dev: command not found

Comment: Command line option 'e' [from -dev] is not understood in combination with the other options.